Apache HttpClient - SSL failures
I'm trying to connect to an endpoint using Apache's HttpClient 4.5, and am running into the below exception:
DEBUG [main] (RequestAddCookies) - CookieSpec selected: default
DEBUG [main] (RequestAuthCache) - Auth cache not set in the context
DEBUG [main] (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager) - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://my-rest-endpoint:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 12; total allocated: 0 of 12]
DEBUG [main] (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager) - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://my-rest-endpoint:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 12; total allocated: 1 of 12]
DEBUG [main] (MainClientExec) - Opening connection {s}->https://my-rest-endpoint:443
DEBUG [main] (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator) - Connecting to my-rest-endpoint/<endpoint-ip-address>:443
DEBUG [main] (SSLConnectionSocketFactory) - Connecting socket to my-rest-endpoint/<endpoint-ip-address>:443 with timeout 0
DEBUG [main] (SSLConnectionSocketFactory) - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
DEBUG [main] (SSLConnectionSocketFactory) - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
DEBUG [main] (SSLConnectionSocketFactory) - Starting handshake
DEBUG [main] (DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection) - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
DEBUG [main] (MainClientExec) - Connection discarded
DEBUG [main] (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager) - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://my-rest-endpoint:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 12; total allocated: 0 of 12]
INFO  [main] (RetryExec) - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://my-rest-endpoint:443: Connection reset
DEBUG [main] (RetryExec) - Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:328)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:355)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:808)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.my.package.rest.MyRestClientImpl.executePostRequest(MyRestClientImpl.java:84)
    at com.my.package.client.MyRestClientTest.test(MyRestClientTest.java:109)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:728)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:218)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:139)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:63)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

Here's how the client is configured:
var httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setMaxConnTotal(clientConfig.maxConnectionsTotal())
        .setMaxConnPerRoute(clientConfig.maxConnectionsPerRoute())
        .setConnectionTimeToLive(clientConfig.connectionLifetime(), clientConfig.connectionLifetimeUnit());

final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .setTrustManagerFactoryAlgorithm("PKIX")
        .setKeyManagerFactoryAlgorithm("PKIX")
        .setKeyStoreType("PKCS12")
        .setProtocol("TLSv1.2")
        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStoreLocation.toFile(), keyStorePassphrase, privateKeyPassphrase)
        .loadTrustMaterial(trustStoreLocation.toFile(), trustStorePassphrase)
        .build();

httpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(sslContext);
httpClientBuilder.setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

final CloseableHttpClient client = httpClientBuilder.build();

try {
    final HttpPost request = new HttpPost(endpoint);
    Map<String, String> customHeaders = Map.of(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json", 
    HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=utf-8");
    customHeaders.forEach(request::addHeader);

    HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    request.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, httpContextThreadLocal.get());
// Do stuff with the response...
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    throw new IOException("Invalid URI request", e);
}

What's perplexing me is that using the built-in Java (17) HttpClient with the same configuration, everything works.
// Configuration for the Java HttpClient
clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
clientStore.load(keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
keyManagerFactory.init(clientStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
trustStore.load(trustStoreLocation, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

SSLContext sslContext = null;
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build();

I'm sure I'm just missing one small configuration option or the like for the Apache client, but I can't figure out what it's doing differently under the hood that's causing the issue, and I can't spot a difference between the requests that the two clients are sending. Is there some obvious configuration option that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Just from looking at the stack trace, it looks like the SSL server is resetting the connection after the client hello is sent. Maybe the server will only do TLS 1.3 and the client will only do TLS 1.2?

If TLS 1.3 is given as well, it'll default to 1.2 anyways, I'm afraid.

I don't know what that means.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk When I send a request via Insomnia app, and TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3 are available, the handshake process seems to settle on using 1.2, is what I meant.

Post complete TLS handshake log as well as HttpClient context / wire log

@quantumferret: Are you sure? A TLS 1.3 client puts the 1.3 version information (0x0304) in a client hello extension rather than in the usual version number field.

@ok2c Sorry, I've just added the remainder of the log I have. Logging was already set up with "org.apache.http" and "org.apache.http.wire" at debug level and picked up by logback via jcl-over-slf4j. Is that what you meant? Or is there something I should provide from another tool, e.g. WireShark?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I wish I was sure - this stuff is definitely not my strong suit - but I'm reasonably confident that it's with TLSv1.2; Wireshark also says that the request is sent over TLSv1.2

Network stuff is hard to figure out remotely. If I was there I'd examine with Wireshark two connections, this one that is failing and the one that succeeds with Java's HttpClient to find exactly what's different between the two. I'd also have ssllabs test the server to see what it supports.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark and https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

I see no TLS handshake log: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

@ok2c thank you for pointing me to that. I have to scrub the logs of a few things, but I'll try to post them soon. One difference I notice between the SSL logs with Apache and the SSL logs with the Java client is that for the Java client, "server_name (0)": {type=host_name (0), value=my-rest-endpoint is present in the extensions section of the ClientHello handshake message, while it's not there with the Apache client. Would that be significant?

Ahh and there's also a warning in the SSL log before the ClientHello handshake message, javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10|main|2024-08-24 17:56:55.163 CEST|ServerNameExtension.java:266|Unable to indicate server name  (for the apache client only)

The problem was indeed the Server Name Indication missing from the client hello handshake message. The solution that worked for me was essentially this answer, with a subclass of SSLConnectionSocketFactory which overrides the prepareSocket method.
